# Bundling external library with custom component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Not sure how else to describe the issue in the title.

I've created a component that can be installed via npm ([Github](https://github.com/Aidurber/VueTagPicker), [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuetagpicker))

My component has a dependency on [vue-touch](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-touch).

When developing the component all is well, the v-touch component is resolved with `tag="li"` so it renders as a li. When it gets bundled however the component doesn't get resolved so it renders as `<v-touch tag="li"`.

In TagPicker.vue I load in the dependency with

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueTouch from 'vue-touch';
Vue.use(VueTouch, { name: 'v-touch' })
//... the rest of the component
```

In index.js which contains the install method for the component I have the following:

```
module.exports = {
    TagPicker: require('./components/TagPicker.vue'),
    install(Vue) {
        Vue.component('tag-picker', module.exports.TagPicker)
    }
}
```

Clearly I've gone about this the wrong way, how would I correctly include the dependency in the bundle?

**webpack.build.config.js**

```
module.exports = [
    {
        entry: "./src/index.js",
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
            filename: "vuetagpicker.js",
            library: "VueTagPicker",
            libraryTarget: "umd"
        },

        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                "process.env" : {
                    NODE_ENV : JSON.stringify("production")
                }
            }),
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
                compress: {
                    warnings: false,
                },
                comments: false
            }),
            new ExtractTextPlugin({filename:"vuetagpicker.min.css",  allChunks: true, fallback:"style-loader" }),
        ],

        module: {
            rules:loaders
        },

    }
];
```

### Edit

I've reverted the commit for the time being. It's worth noting that I was trying to use `v-touch@2.0.0-beta.4` which updated the package from a directive based approach to component based. It left me in a tough spot being forced to use `Vue.use(VueTouch...` since my bundle would then create a dependency on `vue`

Removed the JSFiddle since I've reverted and the example is based of `HEAD`.

My question still remains however, how do we use external plugins inside our external components ready for packaging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

X-Post from VueJS forums where I initially asked this question.

From [LinusBorg](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/bundling-external-library-with-custom-component/14416/3):

> **Adding it globally**
>
> You can't use Vue.use inside a component, it has to be added before
>   you start the main Vue instance (new Vue()...)
>
> **Adding it locally**
>
> adding it locally can't work like you did, because VueTouch is not
>   just the component, its the plugin containing the component.
>
> You can however do this:
>
> ```
> import  { component as vTouch } from 'vue-touch'
>
> ...
>
> components: {
>   vTouch
> }
> ```